# How to manipulate a masonry inside a foreach() loop in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, foreach

I want to have a masonry that I want to have 2 columns, and 2 blocks below each other on the left and 4 on the right as per the image below. I managed to get very close when I used the Jquery Masonry plugin - inside the grid HTML, but number 6 kept going below number 3. And I tried just HTML, Bootstrap containers, the works. The problem starts with the fact that I am using Wordpress and want to display the content by retrieving them from a `foreach()` loop.

Here is the PHP code (I removed the multiple HTML attempts):

```
<?php foreach($homestory as $home) : ?>

    <? $story = get_post($home->ID); ?>

    <div class="block">
        <img src="an_image_pathe_here">
        <?php echo $story->post_title; ?>
    </div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

[image: masonry design I want]

Answer (score 0):

You should forget to use a foreach to make this kind of display.

You should use this kind of syntax to fill your view

```
$homestory[0]->ID;
```

With a bootstrap column system or a css flex layout.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/